# Rails 3, Set i18n locale is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, translation

I am trying to translate my application. I put this in config/application.rb :

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :fr
```

And i create the active_admin.fr.yml file :

```
fr:
  active_admin:
    dashboard: "Tableau de Bord"
    dashboard_welcome:
    welcome: "Bienvenue dans Active Admin. Ceci est la page par défaut."
    call_to_action: "Pour ajouter des sections au tableau de bord, consultez 'app/admin/dashboards.rb'"
    ....
```

If i change the "fr:" to ":en" it's working.

Any idea what i did wrong? (I rebooted apache)

Thank you for help.

**Edit :**

The solution was to use :

```
I18n.default_locale = :fr
```

and not

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :fr
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My answer was to use

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :fr
```

instead of

```
I18n.default_locale = :fr
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 11):

Have you uncommented this line:

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s] # default one has "my" instead of "config", which is wrong
```

I prefer to use this line instead, so it is recursively including files in sub-folders too:

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]
```

Bonne chance!

Comment: Yes i did, but i don't see any difference... still in english.

Comment: My error was to use : config.i18n.default_locale = :fr  instead of I18n.default_locale = :fr

Comment: good news! :) So that did it? Maybe you could mark my answer as the good one? ;)

Comment: No sorry, it's not your answer. You can edit it to say "use : config.i18n.default_locale = :fr instead of I18n.default_locale = :fr " and i validate your answer

Answer (score 5):

@Sebastien answer worked for me, but also:

```
config.i18n.locale = :es
```

I have another application very similar to this one and the default_locale setting works there. Haven't had time to dig into the real problem yet.

**UPDATE**

Found the issue: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/434

Long discussion and still not completely resolved (Sep 2012), one workaround:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :es
I18n.locale = config.i18n.locale = config.i18n.default_locale
```